# Passing parameter Name in confluent HDFS Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Is there any way we can pass the topic names, file name location from config file in the connect HDFS properties.  Right now , we are passing topic name like this :

```
Topic = <topic_1> , <topic_2>
File location = <File_directory>
```

If we are getting topic names in the config file then we need to find the way to pass topic name like this :

Topic=`cat <config_file> | grep topic_name | cut 1-7`        (  This is unix way to read config file.. I am sure we must have some way to read config file in the connect HDFS properties )

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect reads the Configuration as a `Map` object in key value pairs.

The `topics` and `topics.dir` determine where on HDFS the files are written to.

If you want to parse the actual config file locally, you can use `grep` or `jq` (assuming you are using Distributed connect)